# How to print out individual characters of a string in C

Tags: c, string, loops, printf

I'm a bit confused about this here

```
char *string;

scanf("%s",string); 

int i=strlen(string);
int k = 0;

while(k<i){    
      printf("%c", string[k]);
      k++;    
  }
```

and when I compile this it prints out nothing.

Comment: It does get [printed](https://ideone.com/sBhMbQ)

Comment: You also need to print a `\n` at the end, or do `fflush(stdout)`. The standard output is line-buffered by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scanf("%s",string);
```

`string` is a pointer. you need to allocate memory to it so that it can hold the input read using `scanf`.

```
char *string;
```

this statement just creates a pointer to a character array but doesn't allocate memory to hold the array.
You need to allocate memory explicitly using dynamic-allocation. you can use `malloc` like functions. read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164000/how-to-dynamically-allocate-memory-space-for-a-string-and-get-that-string-from-u)

or you can declare a array instead of pointer as,

```
char string[SIZE];
```

SIZE is the maximum possible size of string.
You can use even [getline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744393/how-to-explain-the-parameters-of-getline-in-c) instead of `scanf` since `getline` allocates memory if NULL pointer is passed.

Comment: so i need to use malloc instead of the string in the scanf?

i.e 

scanf("%s", string=malloc((strlen)*sizeof(char)))?

Comment: @yukapuka you will not know the size of the string before reading so you need to read the number then allocate or instead declare a char array.

Comment: @yukapuka you can use getline if you can use it. since it will do the memory allocation.

Comment: how do i read the number? is my only option to read into an string[SIZE] and then find its length strlen(string)

Comment: @yukapuka you will need to ask for length of string from user first then read the string. or you can read the string character by character and allocate memory for one character using `realloc` and then store it and repeat this in a loop. So if can use getline use it directly.

Comment: @yukapuka i added one link for dynamic allocation read it to get idea about how to use dynamic allocation for strings

Comment: that sounds very complicated to use realloc, thanks anyway i understand it now