# Why does strtok interact like this with scanf?

Tags: c, scanf, strtok

So my shell project has been coming along, but my latest speedbump is introducing user input. I'm trying to tokenize an input string, but after the first token `strtok` only returns NULL. But if I hard-write the string in the program, everything works flawlessly. How I can I treat the user input so that `strtok` will tokenize the whole string (instead of the first)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char input[100];
  scanf("%s", input); //input entered is "echo 1 2 3 4"
  char *temp=strtok(input, " "); //this is "echo"
  printf("temp1: %s\n", temp);
  temp=strtok(NULL, " "); //this is (null)
  printf("temp2: %s\n", temp); 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `scanf("%s"...)` which stops reading at the first whitespace character and returns the string. In other words, `scanf("%s"...)` will not read more than one word.

See here under '%s': http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/

`scanf("%[^\n\r]", string_variable)` might be a better idea.

**Update:** As mentioned by Seth in the comments, `"%[^\n\r]"` means read all characters until any of the characters after the `^` is encountered.

Comment: Thank you! Your fix worked perfectly, but would you mind translating `%[^\n\r]` for me? Does the `^` character mean "until?"

Comment: @user1209326 it means "not". It gobbles up characters that match the pattern `[^\r\n]`, which matches "not any of the following: carriage return, newline".

Comment: Oh wow. That's pretty clever. I thought K&Rs mygetline() was an elegant little function, but this is so much simpler. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Beware buffer overflows when the user types more than 99 characters on the command line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the heads up. What's the best practice to avoid buffer overflows in this context?

Comment: @user1209326 for that, you need to use the method I linked to in my answer. It's unfortunately complicated, but it's very solid, and there's no other way to do it without setting a hard limit. If you're ok with setting a hard limit, you can use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/).

Comment: Alright, I guess I should just bite the bullet then. I'll get on that now. Thanks for your help @SethCarnegie!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to read the documentation of the functions you use. The `%s` format specifier "will read subsequent characters until a whitespace is found (whitespace characters are considered to be blank, newline and tab)". That means `input` will only hold the string `echo`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/314422/726361) for how to properly read a line from a file.

Comment: Ugh. I think the hardest part of this project so far is just basic reading comprehension. Thanks for your help!