# How protect dynamic char from being overwritten by second dynamic char?

Tags: c, dynamic, char, overwrite

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char print_two(char *reg, char *s)
{
    int i, l_s = (int) strlen(s), l_reg = (int) strlen(reg);
    for(i = 0; i < l_reg; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %c \n", reg[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char reg;
    printf("Give a rule: ");
    scanf("%s", &reg);

    char s;
    printf("Give a string: ");
    scanf("%s", &s);

    print_two(&reg, &s);
    return 0;
}
```

Program start:

```
Give a rule: qwert
Give a string: asdf
result:
d
q
a
s
d
f
```

How I can avoid overwrite `reg` by `s`?

I tried with realloc, malloc - 0 effect.

Two variables should be dynamic.

Is it possible to do?

---

user give 55 chars -> array 55

user give 100 chars -> array 100

Comment: Just a note beside: I hope you are aware of that `scanf("%s, ...)` is only reading input up to the first whitespace character!?

Comment: I know about this, But thanks for tip :)

Comment: Related answer to read full line of dynamic length: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11917634/1717300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments to other answers, if you are ok with using GNU library extensions (mostly on Linux, or on Windows MinGW), you can use `%ms` in scanf format string, like this:

```
char *reg = NULL; // set to NULL to get segfault on uninitialized use
printf("Give a rule: ");
scanf("%ms", &reg); // scanf will malloc enough space to reg

// check for null in case scanf failed to read anything for some reason
// could also check return value of scanf, which is number of items it got
if (reg != NULL) {
  // process reg
}

free(reg); // free(NULL) is not an error, it just does nothing
reg = NULL; // set to NULL to get segfault on uninitialized use
```

Other answers show how to use a buffer with fixed size, which is standard C. Though according to [`man scanf` notes section](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/scanf.3.html#NOTES), `%ms` might be in a future POSIX standard. GNU also has older `%as`, but `%ms` should be preferred when it's supported (ie. in any modern GNU system).

Comment: No problem, it gave me a chance to update my own knowledge (edited answer just now if you didn't notice).

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%s", ...)` is reading a string from stdin. Your variables reg and s are allocating storage for one character, not for a complete string. You need to change that to `char reg[128]` for example if your input string can be 128 characters long maximum. To prevent a buffer overflow, you should also consider limiting the length of input scanned by scanf using `scanf("%127s", ...)`.

Comment: But when you do not know the amount of data introduced by the user?

Comment: @Jan Czarny: Then it's getting complicated and you have to write your own function that reads the input character by character and stores the string in a dynamically allocated and expanded memory block. In C++ it would be much easier, you could use std::string. In case you are using GCC you can give hyde's approach a try.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read a string (multiple characters) into a single character like `char s`.

You need to reserve more space:

```
char reg[128], s[128];
```

Otherwise random things in memory are getting overwritten, and you're  getting undefined behavior.

Comment: how to accept an unknown number of characters to two data variables?, array make problem with unknown.