# dynamic memory allocation and sprintf

Tags: c

While writing the following code I should get an error. The array size is given as zero(which I suppose is illegal) and furthermore sprintf is printing "abc" to a which has not been allocated any memory but I am getting the output as "abc". I cant understand why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
  {
    char a[0];
    sprintf(a,"%s","abc");
    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
  }
```

I am getting the correct output when i am giving the array size to be 1,2,3 which should not be the case while it is giving segmentation fault for explicitly using a as a pointer ,i.e, using char *a(which is expected). Can somebody explain the internal working?

Comment: It may be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565778/c-how-protect-dynamic-char-before-overwritte-by-second-dynamic-char

Comment: when running `sprintf(char *string,const char *,...)` the pointer to the end of `string` is always defined as `(char *)-1`,or using `vsnprintf(buf,SIZE_MAX,format, arg);`apparently,they are not safe.

Comment: You're most likely overwriting allocated memory in the stack, which is why you get no segfault. If it overwrites data that isn't needed it can seem that everything is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no reasonable explanation. By using an array which is smaller than the string to be printed, your program invokes undefined behavior. That means that literally **anything can happen,** including the fact that everything seems to be working fine. Undefined behavior doesn't mean that the program **must** crash, it means that it **can** crash.