# How to read a line from stdin, blocking until the newline is found?

Tags: c, io, posix

I'm trying to read one line at a time, of arbitrary length, from stdin at the command line. I'm not sure if I'll be able to include GNU readline and would prefer to use a library function.

The documentation I've read suggests that `getline` ought to work, but in my experiments it doesn't block. My sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *line = NULL;
    if (getline(&line, NULL, stdin) == -1) {
        printf("No line\n");
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

produces `No line`, which makes it unsuitable for accepting user input.

How do I do this? I know it should be trivial, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: `getline()` *does* block (just tested on `stdin`). Can you post sample code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a line from the console in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314401/how-to-read-a-line-from-the-console-in-c)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try this patch

```
char *line = NULL;
+size_t size;
+if (getline(&line, &size, stdin) == -1) {
-if (getline(&line, 0, stdin) == -1) {
    printf("No line\n");
} else {
```

Comment: This solves it. And I realize my mistake; I misread the documentation and thought `n` was a `size_t` instead of `size_t *`. Thank you!

Comment: I really like the version control style of the code in this answer.

Comment: Is there an explanation to why this works?  I assumed since the documentation says that the size is ignored when the line is a null pointer, that I can also pass a null pointer to the size.

Comment: @NickMiller: It's the _input value_ of the size parameter that's ignored if the line parameter points to NULL. The size parameter is then set to the size of the buffer that the function allocates for you, that's why it mustn't be NULL.

Comment: when does getline return -1, in STDIN

Answer (score 9):

I have been able to reproduce a "nonblocking" behaviour on `getline`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        char    *buffer;
        size_t  n = 1024;
        buffer = malloc(n);
        return getline(&buffer, &n, stdin);
}
```

`getline(&buffer...` blocks. If I assign `NULL` to `buffer`, again it blocks (as advertised), and stores the line in a newly allocated buffer.

But if I write

```
getline(NULL, &n, stdin);
```

then `getline` fails, and *seems* not to block. Probably also an invalid `n` or file pointer could cause the same behaviour. Might this be the problem?