# Make a c++ program accepts command after started

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to create a program that accepts command through command line.

---

So My program starts like `./program -f filename -m tablesize`. I found that these arguments could be processed by passing arguments to the `main()` function, namely, by doing `main(int argc, char** argv)`.
However, after the program starts, I would like to make it be able to accept input command such as `l key`, which would look up a certain value of ID `key`. **So, how should I make my program being able to accept a variety of commands after it started?**

---

**My Guess**: **Can I just accept input and parse the input ?** I am given that I cannot use any STL to accomplish the work.

Comment: This cannot be done without using the standard library (although I suppose you could use a non-standard library like ncurses).

Comment: @john, Hi! I think I can do this by directly taking input ? And I parse the input by myself

Comment: How are you going to 'directly take input' without using the standard library?

Comment: @john, sorry for the confusion. I cannot use STL instead of standard library :)

Comment: just to clarify, you are not allowed to use functions such as getch() ?

Comment: OK, well then yes, you can directly take input and parse it yourself. Presumably no STL means no C++ strings, so you will have to use char arrays, but it's perfectly possible to work like this.

Comment: @Nathan There is no "STL", there is only the standard library. If your teacher prohibits the use of "STL", they need to define which parts of the standard library they believe that is.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Hi! I found that STL means 'standard template', which includes mostly data structures.

Comment: @john (Bit nitpicky now) It would be possible to work (on most systems) without the STL and even without Standard C libraries if we'd know the target system on which the program has to run.

Comment: @Nathan Standard Template Library (STL) is an obsolete term that technically should no longer be used since (most of) what used to be the STL has been incorporated in the standard library.

Comment: Accepting and using command line parameters does not in any way prevent you from using `std::cin` or  `std::cout`

Comment: STL must mean nothing in the std:: namespace since even cin is an object created from a template.  So you will have to use the stuff in stdio.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to depend upon what your teacher means by "no STL". But let's take your teacher at face value. You have different ways of getting input.

You can use old-school the old-school C library. See this:

[How to read a line from stdin, blocking until the newline is found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252103/how-to-read-a-line-from-stdin-blocking-until-the-newline-is-found)

You can also use C++ streams:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char **) {
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    cout << "Line: " << line << endl;
}
```

I think both of these methods would work for you. I'd use the 2nd.

Comment: This is helpful! Thank you.