# How Should I read a File line-by-line in C?

Tags: macos, unicode, utf-8, getline, fgets

I'd like to read a file line-by-line. I have `fgets()` working okay, but am not sure what to do if a line is longer than the buffer sizes I've passed to `fgets()`? And furthermore, since `fgets()` doesn't seem to be Unicode-aware, and I want to allow UTF-8 files, it might miss line endings and read the whole file, no?

Then I thought I'd use `getline()`. However, I'm on Mac OS X, and while `getline()` is specified in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h`, it's not in `/usr/include/stdio`, so `gcc` doesn't find it in the shell. And it's not particularly portable, obviously, and I'd like the library I'm developing to be generally useful.

So what's the best way to read a file line-by-line in C?

Comment: Yeah, but there are chatterers other than `\n` in UTF-8 that constitute line endings. So `\n` may not even be used in a file.

Comment: If you're reading UTF-8 I recommend you use e.g. `fread` instead, and do the per-line splitting while decoding the buffer. Also remember to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the pointer to `fread()`. In fact, I've switched to `fgetc()`, which seems to work great, and I don't have to worry about parsing strings continued between lines (or buffers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/314422/79202), here's what I've come up with:

```
#define LINE_BUF_SIZE 1024

char * getline_from(FILE *fp) {
    char * line = malloc(LINE_BUF_SIZE), * linep = line;
    size_t lenmax = LINE_BUF_SIZE, len = lenmax;
    int c;

    if(line == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for(;;) {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if(c == EOF)
            break;

        if(--len == 0) {
            len = lenmax;
            char * linen = realloc(linep, lenmax *= 2);

            if(linen == NULL) {
                // Fail.
                free(linep);
                return NULL;
            }
            line = linen + (line - linep);
            linep = linen;
        }

        if((*line++ = c) == '\n')
            break;
    }
    *line = '\0';
    return linep;
}
```

To read `stdin`:

```
char *line;
while ( line = getline_from(stdin) ) {
    // do stuff
    free(line);
}
```

To read some other file, I first open it with `fopen()`:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen ( filename, "rb" );
if (!fp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s: ", argv[1]);
    perror(NULL);
    exit(1);
}

char *line;
while ( line = getline_from(fp) ) {
    // do stuff
    free(line);
}
```

This works very nicely for me. I'd love to see an alternative that uses `fgets()` as [suggested by @paul-tomblin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314401/how-to-read-a-line-from-the-console-in-c/314422#comment156611_314422), but I don't have the energy to figure it out tonight.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's very unlikely that you need to worry about non-standard line terminators like [U+2028](http://www.charbase.com/2028-unicode-line-separator). Normal text files are not expected to contain them, and the very overwhelming majority of all existing software that reads normal text files doesn't support them. You mention `getline()` which is available in glibc but not in MacOS's libc, and it would surprise me if `getline()` did support such fancy line terminators. It's almost a certainly that you can get away with just supporting LF (U+000A) and maybe also CR+LF (U+000D U+000A). To do that, you don't need to care about UTF-8. That's the beauty of UTF-8's ASCII compatibility and is by design.

As for supporting lines that are longer than the buffer you pass to `fgets()`, you can do this with a little extra logic around fgets. In pseudocode:

```
while true {
    fgets(buffer, size, stream);
    dynamically_allocated_string = strdup(buffer);
    while the last char (before the terminating NUL) in the buffer is not '\n' {
        concatenate the contents of buffer to the dynamically allocated string
        /* the current line is not finished. read more of it */
        fgets(buffer, size, stream);
    }
    process the whole line, as found in the dynamically allocated string
}
```

But again, I think you will find that there's really quite a lot of software out there that simply doesn't bother with that, from software that parses system config files like `/etc/passwd` to (some) scripting languages. Depending on your use case, it may very well be good enough to use a "big enough" buffer (e.g. 4096 bytes) and declare that you don't support lines longer than that. You can even call it a security feature (a line length limit is protection against resource exhaustion attacks from a crafted input file).

Comment: Thanks, you're quite right about non-standard line terminators, best not to worry about them at this point. Following @joachim-pileborg's comment, however, I switched to `fread()`, and then, as I read the docs, realized that the `f*()` functions do buffering under the hood, so I might as well just use `fgetc()`. So now I've switched to that, and no longer have to worry about line endings at all.