# C client/server program: server sends answer multiple times when it shouldn't

Tags: c, network-programming

I have the following scenario in C: a simple client program sends HTTP-like requests to a server, which is then supposed to return the input of the specified file. So far, there are only three methods the server should support: GET, HEAD and a default answer for bad requests.

Here's part of the server program:

```
for(;;){
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    int clientAddrLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    int clientSocket;
    
    clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &clientAddrLen);
    
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int bytesRecv;
    
    
    bytesRecv = recv(clientSocket, (char*)&buf, BUFSIZE, 0);
    while(bytesRecv > 0){
        char *method;
        method = strtok(buf, " ");
        printf("method %s\n", method);
        if(strncmp(method, head, 4) == 0){
            /*HEAD*/
            char answer[] = "method: HEAD\0";
            send(clientSocket, answer, sizeof(answer) + 1, 0);
        }else{
            if (strncmp(method, get, 3) == 0){
                /*GET*/
                char answer[] = "method: GET\0";
                send(clientSocket, answer, sizeof(answer) + 1, 0);
            }else{
            
                /*bad request*/
                char answer[] = "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\0";
                send(clientSocket, answer, sizeof(answer) + 1, 0);
            }   
        }
        
        /*Read*/
        bytesRecv = recv(clientSocket, (char*)&buf, BUFSIZE, 0);
    }
```

And this is the part of the client program, that asks to enter a request on the command line and then sends the respective input:

```
char* server_reply[1024];
char* msg[100];

/*send requests*/
for(;;){
    printf("Request:\n");
    scanf("%s", &msg);
    
    if(strcmp(msg, "quit") == 0){
        break;
    }

    send(clientSocket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);

    if(recv(clientSocket, server_reply, sizeof(server_reply), 0) < 0){
        printf("Failure in recv.");
    }else{
        printf("Server: %s\n", server_reply);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is the following: When I enter for example "GET HEAD asd" on the client side, I get three answers from the server, namely

> method: GET
>
> method: HEAD
>
> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

when it actually should only be "method: GET". I really don't understand this beaviour ... Thanks for your help!

Comment: We are working together at this project. But the purpose of my question was another, we encountered this problem after solving the one I've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf("%s", &msg);
```

**Reads strings Not a whole line**. Which means when you enter `GET HEAD asd` your loop runs three times.

First it reads `GET` sends it
and then `HEAD` sends it
and then `asd`

Comment: Ok, is there an alternative to scanf?

Comment: It depends. How do you want to interpret `GET HEAD asd`? as `GET` and then `HEAD asd`?

Comment: I'd like to read the whole line. The server then takes care if GET or HEAD precedes the statement.

Comment: Then check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314401/how-to-read-a-line-from-the-console-in-c

Comment: then use `getLine` from there instead of `scanf`