# Which format should I use: scanf \string,string,int,int/?

Tags: c

I have data in the following format `\a,b,c,d/` where a,b are strings of letters and numbers; c, d are integers.

I tried using format `\%s,%s,%d,%d/` format to scan it, but that causes `a,b,c,d/` to be scanf'ed into the first string instead of only a.

#### Question:

Is there something I could type in the format in order to achieve desired result?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use scanf function (or sscanf, fscanf) ? If not, strtok might be an idea.

Comment: a little experimenting would probably answered your question, do you want to be a programmer or a copy cat?

Comment: perhaps something like:  "\%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d/"  however, may need to double the '\' as that will likely be seen as an 'escape' sequence

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following format string to use commas as delimiters :

```
"\\%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d/"
```

The idea is to [tell scanf to read anything that isn't a comma](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) for each string, then read the delimiting comma and continue.

Here is a (bad and unsafe!) example:

```
char a[100], b[100];
int c=0, d=0;

scanf("\\%[^','],%[^','],%d,%d/", a, b, &c, &d);
printf("%s, %s, %d, %d\n", a, b, c, d);
```

In real code, you'll want to write something safer. You can for example [use fgets to read a full line of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314401/how-to-read-a-line-from-the-console-in-c) then reuse the same format string with [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) to parse it.

Comment: But `%d`  is skipping spaces.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If the input format is `\a,b,c,d/`, that's not a problem.

Comment: No need for `fgets` and parsing. To make it safe all you need are length specifiers on the `%[^',']` format specs to prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes, that would be a solution if each input has a maximum size. Otherwise it's a problem as if one input is too long, the following would not be read correctly.

Comment: @CareyGregory: there are major advantages to reading a line and then scanning it with `sscanf()`.  Most noticeably, you can show the entire line that was entered in the error messages or error log, whereas if you've used the file I/O directly, and characters read successfully will not be available to help identify the line of input containing the erroneously formatted data.

Comment: @tux3 Well, sure, you of course need to check `scanf`'s return code but that's a given.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, the `fgets` approach has some pluses, but it also requires more code, and parsing code at that, which has a habit of being more difficult and more prone to subtle bugs than anticipated.

Answer (score 2):

Read carefully the documentation of [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html).

You might try something like

```
char str1[80];
char str2[80];
memset (str1, 0, sizeof(str1));
memset (str2, 0, sizeof(str2));
int  n3 = 0, n4 = 0;
int pos = -1;
if (scanf ("\\ %79[A-Za-z0-9], %79[A-Za-z0-9], %d, %d /%n",
           str1, str2, &n3, &n4, &pos) >= 4
    && pos > 0) {
   // be happy with your input
 }
 else {
   // input failure
 }
```

<sup>That won't work if you have a wider notion of letters, like French `é`  or Russian `Ы` ; both are single letters existing in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) but represented in several bytes.</sup>

I added some spaces (mostly for readability) in the format string (but `scanf` is often skipping spaces anyway, e.g. for `%d`). If you don't accept spaces -like an input line such as `\AB3T, C54x, 234, 65/` , read each line with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) and parse it manually (perhaps with the help of `sscanf`  and `strtol` ...). Notice that `%d`  is skipping spaces! I also am clearing the variables to get more deterministic behavior. Notice that `%n`  gives you the amount of read characters (actually, bytes!) and that `scanf`  returns the number of scanned items.

Comment: The spaces before `%d` don't do any harm, but they do no good; `%d` skips leading spaces anyway (as do all conversion specifiers except `%c`, `%n` and `%[…]`).

Answer (score -2):

My straightforward solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[10010];

    gets(a);
    int l = strlen(a);

    char storded_first[10010], storded_second[10010];
    char for_int_c[10010], for_int_d[10010];
    int c,d;

    char first_symbol, last_symbol;
    int i;
    int cnt = 0;
    int j=0;

    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]=='\\')
            first_symbol = a[i];
        else if(a[i]=='/')
            last_symbol = a[i];

        else if(a[i]==',')
        {
            cnt++;
            j=0;
        }

        else if(cnt==0)
        {
            storded_first[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
        else if(cnt==1)
        {
            storded_second[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
        else if(cnt==2)
        {
            for_int_c[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
        else if(cnt==3)
        {
            for_int_d[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    c = atoi(for_int_c);
    d = atoi(for_int_d);


    printf("%c%s, %s, %d, %d%c\n",first_symbol, storded_first, storded_second, c, d, last_symbol);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gets` is a pretty dangerous function, some compilers even have a warning for it! Maybe mention that this is unsafe somewhere? Arrays of 10010 elements can still be overrun.

Comment: You used `gets()` — you should never use `gets()` because [the `gets()` function is so dangerous it should never be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).  It is also no longer a part of standard C (as of C11), thank goodness, though it will be available for many years yet (far too many years) for reasons of backwards compatibility. It should never, ever be used in a production program. The first Internet worm (Google search 'morris internet worm') exploited a program that used `gets()` as one of its methods of infection.

Comment: You should also always check the result of an input function such as `fgets()` — the normal replacement for `gets()` — to check that there was any input at all.  You shouldn't use the uninitialized buffer if there was no input.

Comment: That's my thinking and solution. I know that gets is dangerous and its too much code but I had tried to give my solution in my way. You will give your solution in your way. It's simple brothers. Thank you.