# Grade with symbols

Tags: c

i have an assignment which needed me to receive grade input by user..then display it with the grade point..my problem is with the A-,B+,C+ grade..which is the grade which got symbol after it..how do i solve this problem ? how to make it understand ?

this is my code..

`

```
printf("Please enter grade :");
    scanf(" %c",&grade1);

    if(grade1=='A')
        grade_point1=4.0;
    else if(grade1=='A-')
        grade_point1=3.67;
    else if(grade1=='B+')
        grade_point1=3.33;
    else if(grade1=='B')
        grade_point1=3.00;
    else if(grade1=='B-')
        grade_point1=2.67;
    else if(grade1=='C+')
        grade_point1=2.33;
    else if(grade1=='C')
        grade_point1=2.00;
    else if(grade1=='C-')
        grade_point1=1.67;
    else if(grade1=='D+')
        grade_point1=1.33;
    else if(grade1=='D')
        grade_point1=1.00;
    else if(grade1=='F')
        grade_point1=0.00;
    printf("%c %.2f",grade1,grade_point1);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? "How do I do my homework" is not specific enough.

Comment: And it looks more like C, rather than C++.

Comment: Stuff like `'C+'` doesn't fit for a single character.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `standard library` instead of confining to `C` functions.

A `character` can only consist of 1 character. So, to represent an A- you'll need a `string`. This is an `Array` of `characters`.

```
std::cout << "Please enter grade:\n";

std::string grade;
std::getline(std::cin, grade);

if(grade == "A")
{
    grade_point1=4.0;
}
else if(grade == "A-")
{
    grade_point1=3.67;
}
...etc
```

EDIT:

```
std::cout.precision(2);
std::cout << grade << ' ' << std::fixed << grade_point1 << std::endl;
```

Seeing OP changed tag to C:

Use function from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314401/how-to-read-a-line-from-the-console-in-c)

```
char *grade;
printf("Please enter grade: ");

grade = getline();

if(strcmp(grade, "A") == 0)
{
    grade_point1=4.0;
}
else if(strcmp(grade, "A-") == 0)
{
    grade_point1=3.67;
}
etc...

free(grade);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You read the **character** instead of reading the **string**
2. You can not compare strings in `C` with operator `==`. User `strcmp()` instead.

**EDIT**

3. String literals are enclosed in **double** quotes.