# Difference btw gets, scanf('%s'), getline

Tags: c++, c, std

I was reading [this](https://www.quora.com/What-algorithm-questions-were-you-asked-at-an-Amazon-Microsoft-Google-interview) question on quora and read that google asked this question in one of its interviews,

**What are the differences between the functions :
scanf("%s"),gets and getline**

Can anyone provide an exhaustive list and their explanation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314401/how-to-read-a-line-from-the-console-in-c

Answer (score 7):

`scanf("%s", &buffer);` read next token (any space/end of line/tabulation will end the token) in input and store it in the `char *buffer`. You should use a format with a maximum size to buffer, for instance with `char buffer[10]` you should use `scanf("%9s", buffer);` to read at most 9 characters.

`gets()` is obsolete, do not use it. It read a full line, whatever it's size, so if a program with admin privilege uses such a crappy function it can be used by hackers to penetrate the system. This used to be a common hacker's tactic. Please use `fgets()` instead, it takes a parameter with the size of your buffer. `fgets(buffer, 10, stdin);` with my previous example. Please note the `\n` will be included in the buffer if the line is not more than 8 characters.

`getline()` is more specific, for what I know it's a `c++` function only.

Comment: [`getline` is available in C](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), although it is not standard C. It is a POSIX.1-2008 function