# inserting into linked list

Tags: c, struct, insert, linked-list

hello guys i made a program which inserts into 3 linked lists of struct (linked list) , inserting the name , the path and the duration as you can see in the code
, but when im running the project it stucks in this line : 
`fgets(n3->frame->name, 19, stdin);` 
how can i fix that ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Frame
{
    char            *name;
    unsigned int    duration;
    char            *path;  // may change to FILE*
}*p , *p1,*p2;

typedef struct Frame frame_t;

struct Link
{
    frame_t *frame;
    struct Link *next;
}*n , *n1 ,*n2;

typedef struct Link link_t;

struct node *insert(struct node *n3);

int main()
{

    printf("1\n");
    insert(n);


    printf("1\n");

}

struct node *insert(struct Link *n3)
{
    while (n3 != NULL)
    {
        n3 = n3->next;

    }
    if (n3 == NULL)
    {


        n3 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Frame)); //gives memory to the node
        fgets(n3->frame->name, 19, stdin);
        n3 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Frame)); //gives memory to the node
        fgets(n3->frame->path, 100, stdin);
        n3 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Frame)); //gives memory to the node
        scanf("%d",&n3->frame->duration);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some [documentation](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_320.html) for `fgets` says:

> This function reads as much of a line from a file as possible, stopping when the buffer is full (maxlength-1 characters), an end-of-line is detected, or EOF or an error is detected. It then stores a NULL to terminate the string.

The code above does not compile (missing some includes and typedefs?), so I cannot execute it myself, but are you doing things like making sure to hit "enter" after typing in your input?

If you are, I believe you are about to have a whole host of other problems.  One example of how to use `fgets` is in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314401/how-to-read-a-line-from-the-console-in-c) answer, and there are suspicious things with the above code like allocating memory enough for type `struct Frame` but casting it to a separate type and assigning to a third (`struct Link`).  I'd suggest adding the `-Wall` flag to your compilation step if using `gcc` and generally paying attention to warnings.