# Program not executing completely and skipping statements

Tags: c

I have written a simple program in C which is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int length;
printf("Enter the length of the string:\t");
scanf("%d",&length);
char str1[10];
printf("Enter string:\t");
gets(str1);
printf("%s",str1);
return 0;
}
```

When I execute it - I get an output as:

```
Enter the length of the string: 5
Enter string:
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.740 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I don't know why it doesn't ask for the string input and simply quits the program.

Comment: `gets` is deprecated.  Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Thanks William for pointing that out. However, he is a beginner with time he will learn assuming he is a he.

Comment: Duplicate of every other question where people use `scanf` before `fgets`. Also, **NEVER USE GETS**.

Comment: @Rhymoid: The code would be behave the same when using  `fgets()`.

Comment: @alk that is a different point.

Comment: @alk What is your point? That my duplicate flag is correct?

Comment: @Rhymoid is saying that code will behave the same even with `fgets`. Alk has not said anything more.

Comment: @Rhymoid: I seem to have missed the "*Also,...*" before "***NEVER USE ...***". Sry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type '5’ followed by the enter key, you are sending two chars to the program - '5' and newline. So your first `scanf` gets the '5' and the second gets the newline, which it converts to the number zero.

See [How to read a line from the console in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314401/how-to-read-a-line-from-the-console-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

When you enter 5 and press enter which is "\n" then "\n" remains in stream and gets assigned to `str1`. You need to take that "\n" out of the input stream for which many choices are there. You can figure that out. :) Perhaps later I will edit this answer to let you know.

Edit 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int length;
    char c;
    printf("Enter the length of the string:\t");
    scanf("%d%c",&length, &c);

    char str1[10];
    printf("Enter string:\t");
    gets(str1);
    printf("%s",str1);
    return 0;
}
```

This is incorrect way of doing it but your code will at least start working. You can also simply call `getc(stdin)` which is slightly better. The `scanf` regex specified in the other answers where it has been marked as duplicate will also work but is ugly and unnecessarily complicated.

I have not tested this and it may not work.

Comment: I was going to upvote this while reading. But now I have to wait until maybe later :(