# Read a line from console in C

Tags: c

Is crazy enough but there is seems to be very very difficult to read a simple line of chars from the console in C... `gets`, `fgets`, `getline`, `scanf`.... any of these functions does not seem to achieve such a simple thing, read a simple line, without the new line char...

What is that language? I follow [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314401/how-to-read-a-line-from-the-console-in-c), but I don't understand how a language that is so complex to just read a string from console can exist?

Please, could someone guide me how, having a `char* str`, to just read in a console text...

Comment: Use `getline()` (If targeting a POSIXish system) or `fgets()`, if successful, remove the newline at the end of the string. (If using `fgets()` and there is no new line, you didn't give it a big enough buffer to read the entire line so you have to deal with that.) Never use `gets()`, the function so unsafe it was removed from the standard.

Comment: `fgets()` is the function closest to your needs. Ok, there's that trailing newline, but removing that is just a safe (and elegant) [oneliner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/11336762)

Comment: *"but I don't understand how a language that is so complex to just read a string from console can exist?"* - It's a very old language. And no one is forcing you to use it. ;)

Comment: Languages that make the task seem simple thereby hide a substantial amount of complexity to which you must devote attention in C.  Libraries and, yes, higher-level languages are available to relieve you of attending to such low-level details by hand, at the price of not *allowing* you to control details as precisely.

Comment: You could use [GNU readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The link you posted does not work (at least not with me). But that does not seem to be your fault, it seems to be a server problem.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Try then https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Answer (score 3):

The following will read a line from `stdin`, then remove the newline:

```
char buffer[260];
...
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
```

> The C library function char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
> reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string
> pointed to by str. It stops when either (n-1) characters are read, the
> newline character is read, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever
> comes first.

To collect larger amounts of input, this construct can be called within a loop.  Note that how to accumulate each successive buffer is another topic.

More on [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

Comment: Supposing, of course, that the line is no longer than 259 characters, including newline.  The fact that there is no fixed limit on the length of a line is in fact one of the reasons why this is not as easy in C as it is in some higher-level languages.

Comment: Your edit made it worse. Argument 2 for `fgets` has the precise purpose of preventing overflow. And the invokation of `scanf` is plain wrong.

Comment: Actually, except the case of lines longer than the size of the buffer (which is secondary, from the perspective of the question), the first answer was OK, as I stated in my comment above.

Comment: _"fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s"_ ([source](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)). A note, explaining that in case of input lines longer than 259 chars a loop is required, will complete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@ryker provided a good answer that explains the most of it. Here is a pretty safe implementation that is 100% portable and allows you to not bother about neither the newline, buffer overflow or allocation. But it returns a pointer that you need to free.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *gline() {
    char *buffer;

    const size_t step = 10;
    size_t size = step;

    if(!(buffer = malloc(size))) goto CLEANUP;

    char *s = buffer;

    // step-1 is not strictly necessary, but some implementations of fgets
    // are buggy. That's why it's step-1 instead of just step
    while(fgets(s, step-1, stdin)) {
        if(strchr(s, '\n')) break;
        size += step;
        if(!(buffer = realloc(buffer, size))) goto CLEANUP;
        s = &buffer[strlen(buffer)];
    }

    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
    return buffer;

CLEANUP:
    free(buffer);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    char *s = gline();
    if(!s)
        puts("Error reading line");
    else
        puts(s);
    free(s);
}
```

I have not finetuned it, so it's possible that it allocates a little bit more memory than necessary. It's not very efficient either, because it runs `strlen` in every iteration. But as long as the allocations does not fail, it's safe and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

The built in functions like `scanf` will do it but the problem I have with them is that you need to know ahead of time how much input you will receive. What if it's 1 character? What if it's 10000? So I prefer to dynamically allocate memory using `malloc` and `realloc` and build the string as the input is received. This is what I use when I need to read from `stdin` or a file. It is simple enough, probably far from perfect, it simply gets a character from stream and if it isn't the newline or `EOF` it adds it to the string. If the reallocation fails it frees the entire string as I need to have an "all or nothing" approach to building the string. It returns a pointer to the string or `NULL` or any failure.

```
char* get_str(FILE* stream)
{
    char *s;
    int ix = 0, sz = 1, rf = 0, ch;

    if(stream == NULL) {
        s = NULL;
    } else {
        s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * sz);
        if(s != NULL) {
            s[ix] = '\0';
            ch = fgetc(stream);
            while(ch != '\n' && ch != EOF && rf == 0) {
                sz++;
                s = (char*)realloc(s, sizeof(char) * sz);
                if(s != NULL) {
                    s[ix] = ch;
                    ix++;
                    s[ix] = '\0';
                    ch = fgetc(stream);
                } else {
                    rf = 1;
                    free(s);
                    s = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

And then you call it like this:

```
int main()
{
    char *s = get_str(stdin); /* or a file you opened with fopen, etc */

    printf("%s\n", s);

    free(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Just remember that memory allocated with either `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` needs to be freed.